# Generating reproducible IDs with UUID?

Tags: java

I'm using `UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits();` to generate unique IDs. However I want to generate the same IDs every time I run the application in order to debug my code. How can I do that?

Edit: thanks to zim-zam I created this class that solves the problem.

```
public class IDGenerator {
private static Random random = new Random(1);
public static long getID() {
    long id;
    byte[] array = new byte[16];
    random.nextBytes(array);
    id = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes( array ).getLeastSignificantBits();
    return id;
}
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing the point of a UUID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[] bytes)` where you get `byte[] bytes` from a `Random` or `SecureRandom` that you seeded

Comment: how much should I select for the size of the bytes array?

Comment: @guckogucko If you use a 16-byte (128-bit) `byte[]` then it will have the same amount of entropy as the UUID; there's no reason to use a larger byte array, but you can use a smaller byte array if you don't need that much entropy (e.g. if you're only using the least significant bits of the UUID then you can probably make do with an 8-byte `byte[]`)

Comment: can you please check my edit (the code), so I can mark the question as solved?

Comment: @guckogucko `new byte[120]` is overkill - use `new byte[16]` or `new byte[8]`

Comment: Sorry for the late question, but wouldn't it not also be correct to do `new UUID(rng.nextLong(), rng.nextLong())` to get a reproducible UUID?

Answer (score 2):

I would create my own class which wraps the UUID class and that can accept some kind of flag to determine if it's in debug mode in which case it would return a constant value or "production" mode in which case it would work as expected.

An even cleaner solution would be to define an interface like IRandomUUIDGenerator and have two implementations for it: ConstantUUIDGenerator which you can use for your testing and DefaultRandomUUIDGenerator implementation for your production code. You can then specify in a config file which implementation to use depending on your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`java.util.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), providing the same seed.